# C# DocuSign project getting "The type initializer for 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JsonExtensions' threw an exception"

Tags: docusignapi

Looking for some help on why I am getting this runtime error when calling RequestJWTUserToken(). Here is a stack trace:

```
ERROR: The type initializer for 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JsonExtensions' threw an exception. 
 at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JsonExtensions.SerializeToJson(Object value)
 at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtHeader.SerializeToJson() in C:\agent1\_work\109\s\src\System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt\JwtHeader.cs:line 319
 at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtHeader.Base64UrlEncode() in C:\agent1\_work\109\s\src\System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt\JwtHeader.cs:line 277
 at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.CreateJwtSecurityTokenPrivate(String issuer, String audience, ClaimsIdentity subject, Nullable`1 notBefore, Nullable`1 expires, Nullable`1 issuedAt, SigningCredentials signingCredentials, EncryptingCredentials encryptingCredentials) in C:\agent1\_work\109\s\src\System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt\JwtSecurityTokenHandler.cs:line 506
 at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.CreateToken(SecurityTokenDescriptor tokenDescriptor) in C:\agent1\_work\109\s\src\System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt\JwtSecurityTokenHandler.cs:line 468
 at DocuSign.eSign.Client.ApiClient.RequestJWTUserToken(String clientId, String userId, String oauthBasePath, Byte[] privateKeyBytes, Int32 expiresInHours, List`1 scopes)
```

I have loaded the most-recent version of DocuSign.eSign in my project (5.8.0), and I have tried all the way back to 4.0.0 and get the same error.
Here is the source code (basically using the JWTAuth.cs code found in Quickstart). It's the RequestJWTUserToken(...) which causes the error:

```
        var devPlaceholder = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi"; // dev
        ApiClient _apiClient = new ApiClient(devPlaceholder);
        OAuth.OAuthToken authToken = _apiClient.RequestJWTUserToken(
            "55xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx25dd",
            "b5xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx26b4",
            "account-d.docusign.com",
            File.ReadAllBytes("C:\\secure\\pem_quickstart_secret_key.txt"),
            1,
            scopes);
        string accessToken = authToken.access_token;
```

When I used Nuget to load DocuSign.eSign.dll (5.8.0) it also loaded dependencies:

```
BouncyCastle (1.8.9)
Microsoft.CSharp (4.5.0)
Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens (5.4.0)
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging (5.4.0)
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols (5.4.0)
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens (5.4.0)
Newtonsoft.Json (11.0.2)
RestSharp (106.12.0)
System.ComponentModel.Annotations (4.5.0)
System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt (5.4.0)
```

I'm stumped on this one, as I don't know the inner workings of the Jwt assembly, and whether I am just missing some initialization of it or what is happening.

Comment: Which version of .NET? is this a web app or console app? Can you try a simple console app, .NET Core and see if you get it?

Comment: This is a web service app I am compiling with .NET version 4.7.2 (VS2019).

Comment: Is the "RestSharpSigned" module required?

Comment: RestSharp is required, not sure what RestSharpSigned means, do you used signed assemblies?

Comment: Ok, yes, I have RestSharp. I was just looking through search results, and someone talked about using RestSharpSigned and thought it might be needed. All my Assemblies should be signed as they came from Nuget.

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example of working API Call:

```cs
var integrationKey = "";
var impersonatedUserID = "";
var oauthBasePath = "account-d.docusign.com";
var privateKey = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(File.ReadAllText("private.key"));
var scopes = new List<string>
    {
        "signature",
        "impersonation",
    };
ApiClient _apiClient = new ApiClient();
OAuthToken _OAuthToken = _apiClient.RequestJWTUserToken(
    integrationKey,
    impersonatedUserID,
    oauthBasePath,
    privateKey, 1, scopes
);
accessToken = _OAuthToken.access_token;
```

**NOTE**: The `private.key` file should have the property **Copy to output directory** set to *Always copy* or *Copy if newer*.

Comment: I tried your code, and I still get this error:  ERROR: The type initializer for 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JsonExtensions' threw an exception. [ at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JsonExtensions.SerializeToJson(Object value)